# Spark : Can i tuning a pipeline with 2 estimator simultaneously

Tags: apache-spark, machine-learning, apache-spark-mllib, text-mining

I have a flow ( pipeline in Spark ) like this :

1. *I have a DataFrame A, which have strings*
2. *Create a Word2Vec estimator*
3. *Create a Word2VecModel transformer*
4. *Apply Word2VecModel to DataFrame A, to create a DataFrame B,which have vectors*
5. *Create a KMean estimator*
6. *Create a KMeanModel transformer*
7. *Apply KMeanModel to DataFrame B, for clustering*

In this flow, we have 2 estimators and 2 transformer models, so we will need 2 pipeline, and tuning for each pipeline separately.

But can we do tuning in one pipeline ? I have no idea about how to do it , so which methods is the best way for tuning my flow ?

**Edit**:
In Spark-ml lib, input for pipelines components is only dataframe, and output is dataframe or transformer. But if we chain 2 estimator on 1 pipelines, output from estimator 1 will be a transformer, so you can not continue to chain next estimator 2 on same pipeline ( accept only dataframe as input ). So do we have any trick for tuning 2 estimator ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no conflict here. Spark ML `Pipeline` can contain arbitrary number of `Estimators`. All you have to do is to ensure that output column names are unique.

```
val kmeans: KMeans = ???
kmeans.setPredictionCol("k_means_prediction")

val word2vec: Word2Vec = ???
word2vec.setOutputCol("word2vec_output")

new Pipeline().setStages(Array(kmeans, word2vec))
```

However different models typically require different feature engineering steps it not very useful in practice.